# How to save a file in a directory chosen by user in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an image editing app and I have a button that should save a file to external storage when user taps on it. When this button is clicked then I start an activity for the user to select a directory and then when user selects a directory then I override OnactivityResult and check the request code there and then I try and get the uri of the selected folder and I try to save the image there but I keep getting the error that

> could not find a part of the path "/tree/primary:Music/document/primary:Music/file.png"

This is the button event handler

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
//check if the app has permission to manage storage
if(Environment.IsExternalStorageManager){
    //start activity for user to select a folder
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
    StartActivityForResult(intent, DIRECTORY_PICK_UP) ;
    }
}
```

Then inside the OnactivityResult method I process the selected folder like below

```
protected override void OnactivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data) {
    //handle the folder chosen
    if(requestCode == DIRECTORY_PICK_UP && resultCode == Result. Ok) {
       Uri uri = data.Data;
       ContentResolver resolver = applicationContext.ContentResolver; resolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(uri, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
     //debug the could not find part of path 
     string temp = "temp.png";
     SaveImage(uri, temp) ;
}
```

The code am using to save the image to the selected directory is below

```
private void SaveImage(Uri uri, string filename) {

 var imageBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
 string fullPath = string.Empty;
 if (uri.Scheme.Equals("content"))
 {
     try
     {
         Context applicationContext = Application.Context;
         //add read and wrte flags to the intent
         DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.FromTreeUri(applicationContext, uri);
         if (documentFile != null && documentFile.Exists() && documentFile.IsDirectory)
         {
             fullPath = documentFile.Uri.Path;
             Snackbar.Make(pictureBox1, fullPath, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();
             using var stream = new Java.IO.File(fullPath, fileName + ".png");
             try
             {
                 using (FileStream str = new FileStream(stream.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Create))
                 {
                     imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, str);
                     Toast.MakeText(this, "Image save success", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception exc)
             {
                 Toast.MakeText(this, exc.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
             }

         }
     }catch(Exception ex)
     {
         Log.Debug(ex.Message, "WW");
     }
 }
}
```

NB:

Thanks to the community user @blackapps, I have managed to create a blank file in the directory selected with the name the user entered in the dialog box. Now the problem is in copying the bytes from the original bitmap file to the newly created file. Here is what I have tried so far

```
//create a direct child file of the parent folder
DocumentFile docFile = documentFile.CreateFile("image/png", fileName);
fullPath = docFile.Uri.Path;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();

// Write the byte array to a file
try
{
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(fullPath);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOutputStream.Write(bitmapData);
    fileOutputStream.Close();
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Image saved successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
{
    // Handle any exceptions that occur during file writing
    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetTitle("Error");
    builder.SetMessage(e.Message);
    builder.SetNeutralButton("OK", (o, e) =>
    {

    });
    builder.Show();
}
```

Am getting this error

> open failed ENOENT:No such file or directory

How do I successfully copy image bytes from the original bitmap to the output image?

Comment: @blackapps, I put that there because I thought the uri may be unreadable for some reason so that's why.

Comment: @blackapps, how should I take it directly from onactivityResult?

Comment: @blackapps, can you share a sample post link?

Comment: @blackapps, okay doing that right but I doubt it will make a difference because am literally passing the uri object returned by activity on result to the method

Comment: @blackapps, I updated my post

Comment: @blackapps, loved the line and removed the android alert dialog builder from the code.

Comment: @blackapps, the method is back

Comment: @blackapps, function called. Clearing the persistable uri permission on function

Comment: Based on the code you shared, I tried to copy it to my demo and found there were some unknown codes.  Could you please post the latest full code of your current activity?

Comment: @JESSIEZHANG-MSFT, The issue was resolved. The image is saved in a directory user chooses

Comment: Congrats. Could you please share the solution so that others who have similar problems will get help from your solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JESSIEZHANG-MSFT, The solution by back apps works fine all he needs is to update his answer to show users how to use a content resolver to copy bytes to the file uri output stream

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, I added an answer of my own.

Answer (score 0):

> > DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.FromTreeUri(applicationContext, uri);

You cannot use the IO.File class if you work with DocumentFile.

Instead use

```
documentFile.createFile()
```

which gives you an uri to the file for which you can open an OutputStream where you can write to.

Comment: Please reproduce your answer with my code so I can check if it's working, right now I don't know where to put the line you suggested

Comment: If you do it and it works then I will upvote your answer and accept. Which will be a +25

Comment: DocumentFile.CreateFile creates the child file in the selected directory but I cannot copy from the image to it

Comment: Of course that is possible. But where is your code? You did not change anything yet. You really take your time isnt it.

Comment: I updated my question with the Code I am trying to use to copy byes from the Bitmap to the output file

Comment: You should better read what i sugested you to do. And you are still using IO.File class although i said that you could not use it.docFile.getUri() is the uri i talked about. Now open an OutputStream for that uri and compress the bitmap against that stream.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an image byte array and you intend to save that as a file in the directory selected by the user then the code below worked for me

```
//create the child document in the selected directory
DocumentFile docFile = documentFile.CreateFile("image/png",fileName);
//get the uri to the file
Uri uri = docFile.Uri;
//use a content resolver to write to the file output stream 
var resolver = ContentResolver;
using(var outputStream = resolver.OpenOutputStream(uri)) {
  //copy bytes from the image data
   outputStream.Write(imageData,0, imageData.Length);
  }
```